# ionic5 white screen. Why is it not loaded tabs.ts

Tags: ionic-framework

My development environment 
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRvxg.png)

config.xml文件内容

```
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="AllowedSchemes" value="netspay" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

app.component.ts    file part function

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#27507E');
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.splashScreen.hide();
      }, 2000);
    });
}
```

app-routing.module.ts config content

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'products',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/products/products.module').then( m => m.ProductsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'proDetail',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/proDetail/proDetail.module').then( m => m.ProDetailPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'cartPage',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/cartPage/cartPage.module').then( m => m.CartPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'orderDetail',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/orderDetail/orderDetail.module').then( m => m.OrderDetailPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'payment',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/payment/payment.module').then( m => m.PaymentPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'receipt',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/receipt/receipt.module').then( m => m.ReceiptPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'setting',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/setting/setting.module').then( m => m.SettingPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'notification',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/notification/notification.module').then( m => m.NotificationPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'scanner',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/scanner/scanner.module').then( m => m.ScannerPageModule)
  },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

tabs.page.ts part code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('page load');
  }
```

Sometimes the screen appears white on startup. But not every time.
Page load success, display 'page load' log.
Page white screen, Does not display 'page load' log. Please tell why tabs.Page.ts file were not load!
Who can help me! thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered this problem, this is how I fixed it:

1. update your platform-android version to 6.4.0
2. reinstall plugin cordova-plugin-webview